# Changing or "Marking" some elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to "Mark" some elements in a list if they obey certain conditions. I honestly do not know if there is a way to mark elements, so I have decided to create another list where those numbers which obey the criteria will be represented in "1" (And those which do not will be represented in "0").

The condition is `Divisable[2*#-1,3]`

Here is the code, which is not working for a reason.

```
a = 12
blist = 2*Range[a/2] - 2
enter code here
ilist = Table[0, Length[blist]]
Map[If[Divisable[2*# - 1, 3],ReplacePart[ilist, Position[blist, #] -> 1]] &, blist]
ilist
```

The list blist (`{0,2,4,6,8,10}`) has two elements that meet the criteria, and therefore the final output of ilist should be the following:

```
{0,1,0,0,1,0}
```

However, Mathematica outputs the following:

```
{0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

If you could tell me what is wrong with my code and how to properly "Mark" certain elements in a list, I'd be very grateful. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `Boole[Divisible[2 # - 1, 3]] & /@ blist`.

Comment: Thanks, it works well!

Comment: Not as neat as JM's comment, but using your own approach: `If[Divisible[2*# - 1, 3], 1, 0] & /@ {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}`

Comment: Works just as fine!

Comment: `ilist = Boole[Divisible[2 blist - 1, 3]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 blist = 2*Range[12/2] - 2; 

 -Mod[2 blist - 1, 3] // UnitStep
```

> {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. You could define `blist` with `Range[1, 2 a, 4] - 2` and then just `-Mod[blist, 3] // UnitStep`

Answer (score 1):

```
blist = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
1 - Unitize @ Mod[2 blist - 1, 3]
```

> {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}